# How do I solve this problem (leetcode-style technical problem)?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, big-o

Say you are given a list of integer pairs `pairs` and two integers `k1` and `k2`.
Find the count of pairs of pairs from the list that fulfills:

- `pairs[i][0] + pairs[j][0] <= k1`
- `pairs[i][1] + pairs[j][1] <= k2`
- for `i < j`

For example, if, `pairs=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]`, `k1=6` and `k2=7`, the result should be `4`, since `([1,2],[2,3])`, `([1,2],[3,4])`, `([1,2],[4,5])` and `([2,3],[3,4])` all satisfy the condition stated above.

See picture for better description of question:

[image]

Is there a way to can solve this question with better efficiency than O(n^2)? This is my solution so far:

```
pairs = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
k1 = 6
k2 = 7

count = 0
n = len(pairs)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        if pairs[i][0]+pairs[j][0] <= k1 and pairs[i][1]+pairs[j][1] <= k2:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

This is O(n log n) and solves the largest allowed inputs (n=2×10^5) in about 1.5 seconds:

```
pairs = deque(sorted(pairs))
ys = SortedList(y for _, y in pairs)
count = 0
while pairs:
    x, y = pairs[0]
    X, Y = pairs[-1]
    if x + X <= k1:
        ys.remove(y)
        count += ys.bisect_right(k2 - y)
        pairs.popleft()
    else:
        ys.remove(Y)
        pairs.pop()
```

Consider the pairs as (x,y) pairs. Sort them by x-coordinate, then move inwards. Let (x,y) be the leftmost pair and (X,Y) be the rightmost pair.

- If x+X ≤ k1, then, concerning the x-coordinate, the leftmost pair can be combined with *all* other pairs (since X is the *largest*). But how many of them also have a fitting y-coordinate, i.e., y+y<sub>other</sub> ≤ k2? That means y<sub>other</sub> ≤ k2-y. For this, we keep all y-coordinates in a sorted list. Since we want *other* pairs, we first remove the leftmost pair's own y. Then we binarysearch for k2-y, which tells us the number of fitting other pairs. Finally, we remove the leftmost pair from further consideration, since we counted all its contributions.
- If x+X > k1, then the rightmost pair has a too large X to be combined with any other pair. So we just remove its Y from the y-list and remove the pair.

I used [`SortedList`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) there. If we use a Python `list` instead, the algorithm takes O(n^2), because `del` takes linear time. But with a very small constant factor, so it still only takes about 3 seconds for the largest allowed inputs.

Test results with your small example and larger random inputs:

```
4 pairs:
  count=4  0.000 s  original
  count=4  0.000 s  Kelly_SortedList
  count=4  0.000 s  Kelly_list

1000 pairs:
  count=51328  0.144 s  original
  count=51328  0.003 s  Kelly_SortedList
  count=51328  0.002 s  Kelly_list

6000 pairs:
  count=1845645  4.786 s  original
  count=1845645  0.023 s  Kelly_SortedList
  count=1845645  0.012 s  Kelly_list

200000 pairs:
  count=2022417695  1.490 s  Kelly_SortedList
  count=2022417695  2.944 s  Kelly_list

400000 pairs:
  count=8075422313  3.454 s  Kelly_SortedList
  count=8075422313 12.957 s  Kelly_list
```

Code for that:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from collections import deque
from random import randrange
from time import perf_counter as time
from sortedcontainers import SortedList


def original(pairs, k1, k2):
    count = 0
    n = len(pairs)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if pairs[i][0]+pairs[j][0] <= k1 and pairs[i][1]+pairs[j][1] <= k2:
                count += 1
    return count


def Kelly_SortedList(pairs, k1, k2):
    pairs = deque(sorted(pairs))
    ys = SortedList(y for _, y in pairs)
    count = 0
    while pairs:
        x, y = pairs[0]
        X, Y = pairs[-1]
        if x + X <= k1:
            ys.remove(y)
            count += ys.bisect_right(k2 - y)
            pairs.popleft()
        else:
            ys.remove(Y)
            pairs.pop()
    return count


def Kelly_list(pairs, k1, k2):
    pairs = deque(sorted(pairs))
    ys = sorted(y for _, y in pairs)
    count = 0
    while pairs:
        x, y = pairs[0]
        X, Y = pairs[-1]
        if x + X <= k1:
            del ys[bisect_left(ys, y)]
            count += bisect_right(ys, k2 - y)
            pairs.popleft()
        else:
            del ys[bisect_left(ys, Y)]
            pairs.pop()
    return count


funcs = original, Kelly_SortedList, Kelly_list

def test(funcs, *args):
    print(len(args[0]), 'pairs:')
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        print(f'  count={f(*args)}', f'{time() - t0 :6.3f} s ', f.__name__)
    print()

def gen(n):
    pairs = [[randrange(2*10**5), randrange(2*10**5)] for _ in range(n)]
    k1 = 15 * 10**4
    k2 = 17 * 10**4
    return pairs, k1, k2

test(funcs, [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]], 6, 7)
test(funcs, *gen(1000))
test(funcs, *gen(6000))
test(funcs[1:], *gen(2*10**5))
test(funcs[1:], *gen(4*10**5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's `O(n)` space and `O(n log n)` time. Given an order statistic tree, `ys`, the pairs sorted by their first element; and two pointers, `r` at the last pair's index, and `l` at 0:

```
result = 0
while r > l:
  while pairs[l][0] + pairs[r][0] <= k1:
    add pairs[l][1] to ys
    l += 1
  result += count of ys <= (k2 - pairs[r][1])
  r -= 1
while r > 0:
  if r < l:
    remove one pairs[r][1] from ys
  result += count of ys <= (k2 - pairs[r][1])
  r -= 1
return result
```

This adds the number of pairs that can be matched for each pair at the right index. As the window narrows, all the pairs on the left (with smaller first elements) remain candidates, and more can be added as the fixed pair on the right has a smaller and smaller first element. The order statistic tree helps us answer for the pair on the right how many of the candidates on the left also abide by the second element restriction.

(Please note that the pseudocode is untested and may not include handling for all cases, where the pointers are in various states between the code blocks presented.)

Comment: can you provide a python implementation of this? I am quite intrigued

Comment: @KellyBundy actually, it's 3 but it's still wrong :) Let me fix it.

Comment: @KellyBundy `r` goes down to 3 on the second step, adding two more. But I neglected the rest of the iteration since we need to evaluate candidates for *every* right element :) I was hoping to avoid removing from the tree but currently cannot think of an alternative.

Comment: @KellyBundy I was talking about the values not the indexes. How do you figure `l` goes to index 2? That would be 3+4>k1

Comment: @KellyBundy oh because it was always incrementing.

Comment: @KellyBundy never mind. That's less important to me than trying to figure out how not to remove from the tree.

Comment: Seems [almost correct](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/L5CRBKuQ5YT) now.

Comment: @KellyBundy are there some failing edge cases? I'm just writing this off the top of my head :)

Comment: Well, yes, run that and look at the output. You'll see it produces a different result than what the question's original solution and my solution produce. And I think it's a bug in your pseudocode, not in my Python translation. (But ignore the runtimes shown there, that site apparently has bad timers, I only use it for it's short urls.)

Comment: Or, actually I wouldn't call it "edge" cases. Looks like it fails about 20% of random inputs with n=100.

Comment: @KellyBundy thank you! I'll add a note.

Comment: I think you just need to change `while pairs[l][0] ...` to `while l < r and pairs[l][0] ...`

Comment: That is a great answer. In my machine, for n=100k, I get original=`400sec`, kelly's=`0.650sec`, this one=`0.396sec`